# Carbohydrate Chemistry for Candy Making

Tags: carbohydrates, applied-chemistry

I am trying to understand the different behaviors of sugar syrups when it comes to candy making. Specifically, maple syrup vs molasses.

In making maple candy, pure maple syrup is heated to soft ball stage, which is 235F or about 113C. It is then cooled without stirring to 175F (79.5C), then beaten until it becomes opaque and thick, indicating sugar crystals have begun forming. When it cools to room temp, it has a somewhat fudgy consistency and is fairly brittle. If you do the same process with molasses, you get a sort of proto-taffy. In fact, you can pull it, and it will incorporate air, but doesn't quite reach taffy consistency (taffy typically also includes a fat and an emulsifier, and is also cooked just above soft ball stage to 244F so this is probably why).

I've been able to find some resources on the differences in chemical composition. This paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/0963-9969(96)00000-2 tested 80 maple syrup samples and determined the average syrup was 68% +/- 4% sucrose, with less than 1% each fructose and glucose. In contrast, the *Encyclopedia of Food Sciences and Nutrition (Second Edition)* available at https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/molasses lists molasses as 30-40% sucrose, 4-9% glucose, and 5-12% fructose. Since glucose syrup is added to other candies (including taffy, ice cream base, and fondant) to prevent crystallization, I assume the higher level of glucose is what's preventing the molasses from forming crystals and making a candy similar to maple candy?

Maple syrup also has a significantly higher water percentage, 32% on average compared to molasses at 17-25%, so the cooking process to bring maple syrup to temp is longer than it is to bring molasses to temp. Additionally, maple syrup is mildly acidic, with malic acid being the largest contributor. Is it true that with a mild acid the cooking temperature is not high enough to hydrolyze the sucrose to glucose and fructose?

What ultimately drives the crystallization process? If, for example, you added a significant measure of table sugar to molasses to bring the total sucrose percentage up to 75%, and then cooked it as with maple syrup, could you reasonably expect it to crystallize into a solid candy? Would it have to be a higher percentage because of the glucose present? Or is the higher native glucose level an insurmountable issue in terms of the chemistry?

ETA: Is there a food-safe reaction that can be done in a home kitchen to synthesize the glucose and fructose in molasses to sucrose?

(a final note, I have tested this with 3/4 cup of molasses to 2/3 cup sugar, and again got something closer to a very soft and sticky taffy. It is possible that this was simply not enough sugar, and that it needs to be portioned by mass not volume.)

Any insight is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The chemistry of naturally occurring mixtures in food is *very* complex.Some substances could slow or prevent crystallization, others could speed it.What you're doing by experimentation may be the best way to find optimal techniques. As for synthesizing sucrose from fructose and glucose, this is *not* feasible in the kitchen.,

Comment: Sure, but ingredients get pricey and some basic ideas beyond blind experimentation might be useful to direct the experimental methods. Are there guiding principles that govern sugar crystallization in solutions? I'm assuming crystallization of glucose does happen, mostly because it is possible to buy anhydrous glucose crystals, but it doesn't seem to be the primary mechanism in confectionery, and possibly isn't attainable at home. 

And thanks, that was my guess on sucrose synthesis.